# How should systemd-resolved and docker interact?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, docker, systemd

[This](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) section specifies that a Docker container gets a copy of the host's `/etc/resolv.conf`. However, when i run a simple container on Fedora 34, i get a different result:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.

...

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/sh

/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.

...

nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.2
search .
```

The docker container got nameservers of my primary interface maintained by `systemd-resolved`:

```
$ resolvectl dns enp1s0
Link 2 (enp1s0): 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
```

This works when i want to access the Internet. **But does this mean that Docker somehow integrates with `systemd-resolved`?**

Furthermore, i found that there's a problem with running containers requiring my corporate VPN connection. As i understand, DNS requests go straight to my router (192.168.0.*) and not to the virtual interface set up by the VPN. I solved it somewhat artificially by adding `--dns 127.0.0.53 --network host` flags to the `docker run` command.

It won't work with just the `--dns` flag. **Why is the host networking mode necessary?** After all, 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 are not in the container's network either and they work?

Lastly, i found [this](https://github.com/flaktack/systemd-resolved-docker) repository which seems to address the problem but i don't quite get how it works. **Could someone describe the matter more broadly?**

Comment: Please don’t ask too many questions at once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Docker certainly does “integrate” with *systemd-resolved*: By detecting `127.0.0.53` and then not using it. You can see the [relevant code here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/44a430f4c43e61c95d4e9e9fd6a0573fa113a119/components/engine/libnetwork/resolvconf/resolvconf.go#L44):

```go
        if len(ns) == 1 && ns[0] == "127.0.0.53" {
            pathAfterSystemdDetection = alternatePath
            logrus.Infof("detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: %s", alternatePath)
        }
```

Docker then uses */run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf*, which is the non-stub-resolver file that *systemd-resolved* manages. If your DNS client properly integrates with *systemd-resolved*, its DNS servers should also show up in this file, but only while the connection is active.

---

Why does it not work without `--network host`? Because addresses within *127.0.0.0/8* are only reachable on the same host (or, more accurately: network namespace). This is a critical security feature. Inside a different network namespace, *127.0.0.0/8* refers to the *localhost* in this namespace only. Different hosts are accessible like normal using Docker’s default NAT network.

---

The project you found is, in simple terms, a DNS resolver. So basically the same as *systemd-resolved*, except it’s programmed to listen on the Docker default bridge. The requests are delegated to *systemd-resolved*. In reality, it does some more stuff like resolving container names and whatnot.

Comment: _it’s programmed to listen on the Docker default bridge_ : Just to clarify that point, you mean it's listening on port 53 of the host's `docker0` interface?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though it does not rely on the name but instead queries Docker for it.

Comment: Is this documented in more detail anywhere? Because it doesn't appear to work for me: I get 8.8.8.8 in my container's resolv.conf instead and that DNS server is blocked.

Comment: @cdleonard Is what documented? If you get an unexpected `resolv.conf` in your containers, you could always turn up the Docker log verbosity to get a better grasp of what’s going on.

Answer (score 4):

Add the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/docker.conf with the following data:

```
[Resolve]
DNSStubListenerExtra=172.17.0.1
```

then restart resolved daemon:

```
service systemd-resolved restart
```

Now systemd-resolved is running a DNS server on the default docker bridge network.

```
docker run --dns=172.17.0.1 ...
```

and the DNS lookups will go via your systemd-resolved configuration.